# How to get immediate children count of a HTML node in c++?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, winapi, dom, mshtml

I have tried with this code below, which is not returning the correct child count.

```
    long getHTMLCollectionChildCount (HWND hWnd, POINT point){
    RECT rect;
    SetRectEmpty(&rect);
    CComPtr<IHTMLElement> elementFound;
    //This method returns the element based on mouse point
    findElement(hWnd, &point, &rect, &elementFound);

    CComPtr<IDispatch> pDispatch;
    CComPtr<IHTMLDOMNode> pNode;
    HRESULT hr;
    long lLen = 0L;

    if(elementFound){
        hr = elementFound->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDOMNode, (void**)&pNode);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pNode){
            hr = pNode->get_childNodes(&pDispatch);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pDispatch){
                CComPtr<IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection> pNodeCollection;
                hr = pDispatch->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection, (void **)&pNodeCollection);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pNodeCollection){
                    pNodeCollection->get_length(&lLen);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return lLen;
```

Please care to mention, where it is going wrong or any snippet to do it would be great!

1. The image below to show the children count from c++ as a tooltip which is showing: **9**
   [image: The image to show the children count from c++ as a tooltip]
2. The image below to show the actual children count from developer option which is: **4**

[image: The image below to show the actual children count from developer option which is 4]

Comment: There is no HTML node in the C++ standard. At least you should name the lib you are using. What does _not returning the correct child count_ mean?

Comment: This is windows' own lib, which is available in windows.h and when i check using developer tool option, the immediate child count is not always same as the count it returns in c++. most of time it varies.

Comment: It could be helpful if you post a snippet of HTML where the sample code returns the wrong number of children, what it *actually* returns and what you *expect* it to return.

Comment: Just a suspicion (I am blind so cannot deal with the images), the windows collection is telling you both attribute and child elements count where the other tool is telling you only child elements count.

Comment: There is no way for us to tell, whether you are inspecting the same element. Your first screenshot merely shows a tooltip, without any information, which element it refers to. This question in its current form us unlikely to be answerable.

Comment: The tooltip from c++ (first image) shows the immediate children count for the highlighted html element, which is **9**,  to crosscheck the count value, if I use developer option (second image), the immediate children count is **4**.

Comment: It helps to get actual children count using CComPtr<IHTMLElement> instead of CComPtr<IHMTLDomNode>, cause IHTMLDomNode gets unnecessary **TextObject**s.